# How to make Nivo Slider to fit on any screen resolution

Tags: html, css, slider, nivo-slider

Hello i have a problem with my nivo slider.. I want it to fit automatically any screen resolution and not stay fixed in a specific width.. I saw other similar questions about the same problem but none of the answers helped me... Here is the css code:

```
    /*
          * jQuery Nivo Slider v2.7.1
          * http://nivo.dev7studios.com
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Gilbert Pellegrom
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * March 2010
 */ 


/* The Nivo Slider styles */
.nivoSlider {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        left:0;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    display: block !important;
        position: relative !important; 
        width: 100% !important;
}
/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:6;
    display:none;
}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
}
/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:0.8; /* Overridden by captionOpacity setting */
    width:100%;
    z-index:8;
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav a {
    position:relative;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: If you can provide live example of your running code, it will be better to understand your problem. Please set up part of your code on jsFiddle or codepen and share the link in your question.

Comment: If you are facing problem in small screens only then try adding `max-width: 100%` to `.nivoSlider img` class. Also see if you can remove `!important` from `width: 100%` of `.nivoSlider img` class.